# Java 8 LocalDateTime dropping 00 seconds value when parsing date string value with 00 seconds like "2018-07-06 00:00:00"

Tags: java, datetime, java-8

The code (Java 8) snippet below drops the **seconds part** of my **date time** when the seconds value is **zero** within the date parsed using ***LocalDateTime.parse***, like 2018-07-10 00:00:**00**:

```
final DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
final LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2018-07-06 00:00:00", dateTimeFormatter);
final String lexicalDate = localDateTime.toString();
System.out.println("Lexical Date : "+ lexicalDate);
final XMLGregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(lexicalDate);
System.out.println("Gregorian Calendar : "+ gregorianCalendar);
```

The Lexical Date is printed as :

> Lexical Date : 2018-07-10T00:00

instead of :

> Lexical Date : 2018-07-10T00:00:00

Now this is affecting the date value of the gregorian calendar which **returns null** when the second is dropped. Other cases when the seconds value is greater than Zero, it works perfectly.

```
javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(lexicalDate)
```

The above code is returning null whenever the seconds value is dropped because of 00 seconds value within the parsed string.

Can someone assist with a better way that handles this issue using LocalDate time, otherwise it might be a bug/funny control in Java 8 LocalDateTime.

Please note I do not have control over this date value, it's coming from a third party platform.

Comment: Why is it that you want an `XMLGregorianCalendar`? Asking because if it’s to get an XML string to use in XML, it seems to me you are only using the class for getting the same string back that you put in, a step that you may consider skipping.

Comment: Well, I have a class I am using to bind WSDL dateTime/date using <jaxb:globalBindings>. By default JAXB is generating javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar for any dateTime or date type field in the WSDL. My WSDL generated classes have date fields as XMLGregorianCalendar. I resorted to using jaxb global bindings because the WSDL I am consuming is inconsistent in terms of the dateTime values because sometimes it's returning a date without the time component and thus ending up receiving null date values from the client side.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## Feature, not a bug

You are seeing the documented behavior of the particular `DateTimeFormatter` used by the  [`LocalDateTime::toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#toString()) method.

Excerpt, my emphasis:

> The output will be one of the following [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats:
>
> uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm
>
> uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss
>
> uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS
>
> uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS
>
> uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS
>
> The **format used will be the shortest** that outputs the full value of the time where the **omitted parts are implied to be zero**.

If you want other behavior when generating a String to represent the value of you [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html), use a different [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) and pass it to [`LocalDateTime::format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#format(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter)).

```
String output = myLocalDateTime.format( someOtherFormatter ) ;
```

The `LocalDateTime` has no “format” as it is *not* text. It is the job of the `DateTimeFormatter` to parse or generate [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) objects of a particular format.

Comment: To clarify, the fact that you use a formatter to create the `LocalDateTime` instance doesn't mean that the instance will remember it, you're just indicating the shape of the string you'll give to `LocalDateTime::parse`; ergo, it doesn't affect `toString`

Answer (score 5):

DateTimeFormatter removes 00 from date after parsing, you just have to reformat it again

please refer below code snippet:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String currentTime= "2017-10-19 22:00:00";
LocalDateTime datetime = LocalDateTime.parse(currentTime,formatter);
//2017-10-19T22:00
String formattedDate=datetime.format(formatter);
//2017-10-19 22:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I don’t think that “DateTimeFormatter removes 00” is strictly correct, I am sure that the 0 seconds are still represented internally in the resulting `LocalDateTime` object. Rather it was `LocalDateTime.toString()` not printing them as explained in the answer by Basil Bourque.

Answer (score 4):

You need to format your date with the proper formatter instead of using default one by calling `toString()`.

```
final String lexicalDate = localDateTime.format(dateTimeFormatter);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this pattern bellow in order to achieve the desired format:

```java
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz");
```